# How to handle (ASCII=92) state=1 error?

Tags: php, twitter

I used codebird-php to post on twitter, but I got some weird Error , the below code I used for posting on twitter :

```
    <?php

     include_once('codebird.php');

line 13:    \Codebird\Codebird::setConsumerKey("0XXmaMkjklJmFRzQYDZSzV7AO2yrl", "EQQVMobir1DzMAmZ5funRXFPSB3VzOUIBEqxvkjklheoLVLHoRuSLz");
    $cb = \Codebird\Codebird::getInstance();
    $cb->setToken("431600336-lvqf6TkljklfWZJw27h3MgKq779BHvMniW0YikkyrMmAe", "uvypmjyBtLFTNpre8wph183ablklkNNcBrqabzhtPSG8T6jVL");

    $params = array(
      'status' => 'Auto Post on Twitter with PHP http://goo.gl/OZHaQD #php #twitter'
    );
    $reply = $cb->statuses_update($params);
    ?>
```

and the below Image this is my error :[image]

Guys I need you comment . how to solve this problem ?

Comment: In the code you posted, which one is the line 13?

Comment: $params = array(
  'status' => 'Auto Post on Twitter with PHP http://goo.gl/OZHaQD #php #twitter'
);
$reply = $cb->statuses_update($params);
?>

but line 13 is : \Codebird\Codebird::setConsumerKey("0XXmaMkjklJmFRzQYDZSzV7AO2yrl", "EQQVMobir1DzMAmZ5funRXFPSB3VzOUIBEqxvkjklheoLVLHoRuSLz");

Comment: PHP Information Version 5.2.6 ----> but how to handle that , how to upgrade it

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are using a PHP version below 5.3 – but namespaces only exist from 5.3.0 on.

And https://github.com/jublonet/codebird-php *clearly states* that it requires PHP 5.3.0 or higher.

Comment: how to upgrade my php version ?

Comment: That depends on what system/environment you are using – and is generally to broad to be answered here.

Comment: Are you running this code on your own computer? If so, go and figure out how to upgrade to a new PHP version. If you are running this on the server of some hosting provider – ask them about it.

Comment: yeah am running on my pc on localhost , and I use apache

Comment: Then I assume you did not install Apache & PHP yourself, but used a pre-configured package? Go download a current version of it then.